Count characters in column from csv
My dataset is being read from a csv file that has 101,777,660 entries, 3 total columns. I am trying to count the number of times these five layers/words occur in the third column (ORIG_NAME): "Slope19_Merged_forest", "CS19_Merged_Forest", "AWY19_Merged_Forest, "TWI19_Merged_Forest", and "Frag19_Merged_Forest"
An example of the dataset looks like this in the csv file:



OVERLAP_OID
ORIG_OID
ORIG_NAME




1
1
Slope19_Merged_forest


2
4
Slope19_Merged_forest


3
5
AWY19_Merged_Forest


4
7
Slope19_Merged_forest


5
9
TWI19_Merged_Forest



My initial code looks like this:
overlay <- read.csv("OverlayTable4.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

I have tried this code:
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
overlay <- tibble (ORIG_NAME = c("Slope19_Merged_forest", "CS19_Merged_Forest", "AWY19_Merged_Forest", "TWI19_Merged_Forest","Frag19_Merged_Forest"))

overlay %>% group_by(ORIG_NAME) %>% summarise (n = n()) %>% arrange (desc(n))

I got this result but this is not what I am looking for:
A tibble: 5 × 2

ORIG_NAME                 n
<chr>                 <int>
1 AWY19_Merged_Forest       1
2 CS19_Merged_Forest        1
3 Frag19_Merged_Forest      1
4 Slope19_Merged_forest     1
5 TWI19_Merged_Forest       1

I expect the outcome to give this type of information:



header 1
Total




Slope19_Merged_forest
200,000


AWY19_Merged_Forest
341,000


TWI19_Merged_Forest
500,000


CS19_Merged_Forest
1,000,000


Frag19_Merged_Forest
90,000,000




It's because the overlay tibble that you applied summarise() to has only one record per group. You need to apply it to your actual data. First run overlay <- read.csv("OverlayTable4.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ","), then overlay %>% group_by(ORIG_NAME) %>% summarise (n = n()) %>% arrange (desc(n)). This assumes OverlayTable4.csv gets loaded correctly and has a column called ORIG_NAME.
